# Use a for-loop for the same procedure on multiple databases

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to condense my code by using a for-loop. Currently I have the following:

```
log.1 = log(canine.dg.16.1$claimedamountSum)
log.2 = log(canine.dg.16.2$claimedamountSum)
log.3 = log(canine.dg.16.3$claimedamountSum)
```

etc. for 1:36

Is there a way to not have 36 lines of code but instead have a for-loop that will repeat this process for each data frame (1:36)?

Answer (score 3):

We can get the datasets into a `list` and apply the code in the `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "canine\\.dg\\.16\\.\\d+$")), function(x)
         log(x$claimedamountSum))
```

Instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment, it is better to store the output in a `list`